# Google Maps Polygon editing - get latlng position on mouseup

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to write a simple snapping function for editing a polygon in Google Maps v3.9

I have several polygons on the map, which can be made editable one at a time.
When one is made editable, I also add a listener to it, to trigger when a vertex has been dragged.

As there is no drag event for `google.maps.Polygon`, I add a `mousedown` listener, which checks if a vertex is beneath the cursor, and if so adds a `mouseup` listener.
The code within this `mouseup` listener checks against the vertices of all other polygons, and updates the dragging vertex if a close match is found.

This works well, except for one problem.  The check is performed using the `latLng` property of the `PolyMouseEvent` returned by the `mouseup` listener.  This property points to the location of the vertex *before* it was dragged, and I can't find a way to reference the vertex in its new position.

```
dragListener = google.maps.event.addListener( poly1, "mousedown", function( dragData ) {

    // if dragging a vertex
    if ( dragData.vertex != null ) {

        // perform snap on mouseup
        snapListener = google.maps.event.addListener( poly1, "mouseup", function( mouseData ) {
            var editingVertex = mouseData.vertex;
            var draggedLatLng = mouseData.latLng;

            // code here to compare draggedLatLng with latLng of editingVertex
            // and perform snap, which seems to work fine as is...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, and i could not find any solutions...

Comment: I wrote a library to solve this issue. Please see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33338065/568884)

Answer (score 4):

Polygons are a collection of paths, and paths are [MVCArrays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) of [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) objects, so we can listen for the `set_at` event on each path in the polygon which tells us when a point has been moved.

```
poly1.getPaths().forEach(function(path, index){
  google.maps.event.addListener(path, 'set_at', function(index, oldLatLng){
    var newLatLng = path.getAt(index);
    // Now you have both the old and new position
  });
});
```

If you know that your polygons never have more then one path (inner rings) then you can just do this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(poly1.getPath(), 'set_at', function(index, oldLatLng){
  var newLatLng = path.getAt(index);
});
```

Though I recommend the first one because you never know when a polygon with multiple paths might somehow sneak in.

Comment: What this doesn't seem to do is get you the position of the vertex as it's being dragged, the "set_at" event is only called when you drop the vertex in it's new position. Anyone find a way to get the position of the vertex while being dragged?